# How are the Forks connected in the Trident?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, map

In the maps at the beginning of *A Song of Ice and Fire* books there is something that tickles me: on the map of "The North", the Red Fork and the Blue Fork flow into each other and meet the Green Fork downstream; yet on the map of "The South", the Green Fork and the Blue Fork flow into each other and meet the Red Fork downstream.

On some unofficial maps, the Trident makes some kind of "delta" at the confluence of the three Forks (they look a bit like lakes) so it might be difficult to say where exactly a fork meets another, but that's not the case on the official maps I've found (*The Lands of Ice and Fire* or at the beginning of each book).

I know George R. R. Martin stated that the maps weren't definitive because he can't (in a way) afford to be too precise since he still have to write the story (so there will be other travel paths that aren't described yet); and because the maps are supposed to be drawn by maesters *in-world* who don't have the same tools as we do to observe the world (there might as well be unknown places where no one went, or that no one made report of). But the Trident is a well known place and many boats are sailing its forks, so there should not be too much confusion about the confluences.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The official maps from the books depict the rivers flowing with a regular course, without forming lakes other water bodies. In all of them, the Green and Blue fork form a confluence, then are met by the Red Fork downstream.**

The maps show this area as follows. All of them are taken from the ebook versions, the left ones are from *The North* maps, the right ones from *The South*.

### A Game of Thrones

> [image] - [image]

---

### A Clash of Kings

> [image] - [image]

---

### A Storm of Swords

> [image] - [image]

---

### A Feast for Crows

> [image] - [image]

---

### A Dance with Dragons

> [image] - [image]

---

### The Lands of Ice and Fire

> [image]

Comment: I thought the maps of all books were the same, so I did some research and it appears that those maps are drawn by James Sinclair and Jeffrey L. Ward (for ADWD). I (stupidly ?) thought that the maps I've got in my paperback books were drawn by GRRM because of the _R.G_ signature. In fact I've got the UK edition (Harper Voyager) and its maps were drawn by Richard Geiger, who seems to have made some mistakes...

Comment: Just a note that only the maps in The Lands of Ice and Fire are canon.